# In the context of ARPG video game, what is the best translate for "build"?

Tags: translation

In video games, like Diablo, the killing power of our characters can be modified by the skill set (选技），itemizations (配装）， attribute allocations (加点）or more mechanics (depending on the game).

Given one game, a build is a thorough plan/strategy that exhaustively dictates the execution of all power related game mechanics, with minor variations.

The question is how do we translate "build"?

I think "攻略‘ is a close one. But it means "guide" which is a superset of "build". A guide can contain multiple builds. Or a very detailed explanation of one build. But a build usually only describe how we utilize all the game mechanics without explaining why.

In the first paragraph, I listed some subset of "build" such as 配装. Obviously, they are not adequate.

Comment: 攻略 literally means "attack strategy"

Comment: @TangHo, you are right. Edited.

Comment: In a gaming context, many just say "build"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this question for a long time, I found that `流` is the word I am looking for.

For example, a critical-strike build can be translated as `暴击流`.

Answer (score 1):

构筑 is close, though more often refers to "team build" or "deck build"(in card games)

Answer (score 0):

> 組建組態中的建置專案

多個組建 could be related to multiple builds.

Build could be 多個組建組態中的建置專案 or simply 建置專案。